# Cannot start Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net

I have a small asp.net application (only one aspx page). It used to work previously, but now as I try to run it locally through Visual Studio (2010), it doesn't work:
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
Could you please tell me what I could do about it?
Thanks.

Comment: Does your application build successfully?

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET web server, IIS Express, or a full version of IIS?

Comment: Yes, it built successfully. I am not sure what I am using, whatever VS 2010 uses to run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup the project to use IIS Express or the Visual Studio Development server, instead of the one on your local machine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx

Comment: May I ask why it worked previously, but not now? I mean, how using  IIS Express or the Visual Studio Development server should help me? Also, if it really can help, could you please give me a hint how I can apply it?

Comment: It's possible you had it setup to use your local IIS instance, and for some reason that IIS instance is gone (moved), maybe when the upgrade occurred.  Using the Development server will be dynamic with a dynamic port. Just right click on your ASP.NET project, select properties... you'll find it in there.